# Using github to write a book

Tags: github, github-pages, githooks

With Github one can write a well-formatted README.md file and document to present the project. Also, there are wiki pages for user to collaborate. I'm wandering what would be an optimal workflow, even for non tech users, to make use of the GitHub platform to write a collaborative book.

How to use markdown but then enhance it by applying a stylesheet, make PDF out of it, organise chapters, have a public site (gh-pages) out of it and so on? Is there such a project or tool chain for GitHub?

In other word, how to easily write a collaborative book with a nice html and PDF output in GitHub? Thanks.

Comment: This question is not too broad and closing it while it has a single answer acts more like an advertisement for the product mentioned in that answer. We would make a big disadvantage too all SO users by preventing them to propose alternatives.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edit:** GitBook has changed significantly since I first wrote this answer. PDF support has been dropped, and the CLI toolchain [has been abandoned in favour of a proprietary service](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/blob/master/README.md):

> As the efforts of the GitBook team are focused on the GitBook.com platform, the CLI is no longer under active development.

In mid-2019 [mdBook](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/mdBook/) is a good option, though it doesn't natively support PDF. If you have Rust and Cargo installed you can simply

```
cargo install mdbook
```

to get started.

---

**Original answer:**

This is exactly what [GitBook](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook) is designed for:

> GitBook is a command line tool (and Node.js library) for building beautiful books using GitHub/Git and Markdown (or AsciiDoc).

It [supports PDF output](http://toolchain.gitbook.com/ebook.html) out of the box, as well as online publishing on [its own web platform](https://www.gitbook.com/).

Comment: Gitbook removed PDF export in V2 so this answer really doesn't apply any longer.  Here is a CLI tool that will create a PDF from a v2 Gitbook export: https://www.forgebox.io/view/gitbook-exporter

Comment: @BradWood, I think your comment deserves to be a second answer.

Comment: Thanks, I would but sadly this question has been closed.

Comment: Then I guess I'll just upvote your comment :-)

Comment: GitBook is now solely a commercial service unfortunately.

Comment: @RubenSteins, that's correct. GitBook has changed pretty dramatically in the past four years. Thanks for your comment reminding me to update my answer. Please see if this answer now helps.